# filter notation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, cardinals, filters

I've come across this notation

$$\cal D^+,$$

where $\cal D$ is a filter over some cardinal $\lambda.$ If I remember correctly they said that this is the set of all **positive** sets, but I
cannot remember precisely what was the definition of $\cal D^+$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A set $A \subseteq \lambda$ is $\mathcal{D}$-positive if for every $B \in \mathcal{D}$, $A \cap B \neq \emptyset$.